# Группировка меток на карте

Tags: карты, javascript, алгоритм

Интересует алгоритм группировки меток на google/yandex картах. Так как существующие методы отдают некоторой тормознутостью. (MarkerManager'ы yandex api...)
Визуализация неплохо сделана в realty.yandex.ru (для групп маркеров балун также показывает несколько вариантов), но к сожалению и на яндексе подтормаживает. 
Дополнительный минус существующих решений в том, что при изменении масштаба карты, маркеры приходится отрисовывать/группировать заново.

Жду хороших советов.

**UPD**: К сожалению, (к счастью?), ни то, ни другое, ни третье меня не устроило. Пришлось написать свой велосипед. Велосипед получился, как ни странно, с блекджеком и довольно таки быстрый.

Comment: Перегуглил множество решений, но они мне не нравятся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Яндекс карт имеет встроенный кластеризатор. Вот здесь описание его использования: [кластеризация в API Яндекс.Карт 2.х](http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/klasterizaciya-v-api-yandeks-kart-2-x). При очень большом количестве меток рекомендуется использовать механизм активных областей: [кластеризация меток на Яндекс.Картах – два решения](http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/klasterizaciya-metok-na-yandeks-kartax-%E2%80%93-dva-resheniya).

И еще статья по теме [кластеризация на клиенте или как показать 10000 точек на карте](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145832/). И если есть желание сделать все самому теория: 
[A Tutorial on Clustering Algorithms](http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/hierarchical.html).

Comment: Да уж. Мало кого устраивают предлагаемые методы. Стараются написать свои велосипеды. (вот и я тоже...)