# Как сделать группировку меток yandex map API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, frontend

Наткнулся на этот пост [Группировка меток на карте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159168/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5) но на практике выкидывает не понятные ошибке http://dten.pokt.store/project.php - это ссылка на сайт

А вот код самого API

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
      
        function init(){ 
     var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
       center: [48.480223, 135.071917],
       zoom: 5,
        controls: []

     }); 
     myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([48.480223, 135.071917], {
            // Чтобы балун и хинт открывались на метке, необходимо задать ей определенные свойства.
            balloonContentBody: "<div class='ballon-body'><div class='ballon-ttl'>ОАО “Аквапарк Хабаровск”</div><div class='ballon-more' data-more='0'>Подробнее</div><div class='ballon-img'><img src='static/imgs/ballon-img.png'></div></div>",
      
         }, {
            // Опции.
      hideIconOnBalloonOpen:false,
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: 'static/imgs/placeholder.png',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [50, 64],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        });
    myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([50.480223, 135.143917], {
     // Чтобы балун и хинт открывались на метке, необходимо задать ей определенные свойства.
     balloonContentBody: "<div class='ballon-body'><div class='ballon-ttl'>ОАО “Аквапарк Хабаровск 2 ”</div><div class='ballon-more' data-more='1'>Подробнее</div><div class='ballon-img'><img src='static/imgs/ballon-img.png'></div></div>",
    }, {
     // Опции.
     // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
     iconLayout: 'default#image',
     // Своё изображение иконки метки.
     iconImageHref: 'static/imgs/placeholder.png',
     // Размеры метки.
     iconImageSize: [50, 64],
     // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
     // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
     iconImageOffset: [-5, -38],
     hideIconOnBalloonOpen:false
   });
    myPlacemark3 = new ymaps.Placemark([48.498223, 138.071917], {
     // Чтобы балун и хинт открывались на метке, необходимо задать ей определенные свойства.
     balloonContentBody: "<div class='ballon-body'><div class='ballon-ttl'>ОАО “Аквапарк Хабаровск 3”</div><div class='ballon-more' data-more='2'>Подробнее</div><div class='ballon-img'><img src='static/imgs/ballon-img.png'></div></div>",
    }, {
     // Опции.
     // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.'
     hideIconOnBalloonOpen:false,
     iconLayout: 'default#image',
     // Своё изображение иконки метки.
     iconImageHref: 'static/imgs/placeholder.png',
     // Размеры метки.
     iconImageSize: [50, 64],
     // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
     // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
     iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
   });
     myGeoObjects = [myPlacemark,myPlacemark2,myPlacemark3];
     clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer();
     clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
     myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
      
     var clusterIcons=[{
     href:'static/imgs/placeholder.png',
     size:[53,52],
     offset:[0,0]
     }],
     clusterNumbers=[100],
     clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
     margin:[20],
     clusterIcons:clusterIcons,
     clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
     clusterNumbers:clusterNumbers
     });
     myMap.behaviors.enable('multiTouch');
     myMap.controls.add('zoomControl');

     myMap.behaviors.enable('drag');
       myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
       myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
       myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark3);

     myMap.panes.get('ground').getElement().style.filter = 'grayscale(100%) brightness(40%)';

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы добавили метки в кластеризатор, то не нужно добавлять их отдельно на карту. Удалите:

```
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark3);
```